# How can I display from a script block with Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm **trying** to learn Razor/MVC3 and having a bit of trouble with this partial view DisplayTemplate.

```
@{
    DateTime? date = ViewData.Model;

    if(date.HasValue) {
        date.Value.ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```

This is what I'm trying to do. Obviously I'm not doing it correctly, because it's not working. I've tried it several different ways I could think of and only received random errors. This method simply doesn't return anything ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not rendering anything to the page with this syntax; all that code does is declare a variable *date* and set it to a value in the model.  Try something like this ...

```
@{
    DateTime? date = ViewData.Model;
    string displayDate = "";

    if(date.HasValue) {
        displayDate = date.Value.ToShortDateString();
    }
}

@displayDate
```

Or even simpler, just this:

```
@if (ViewData.Model.HasValue) 
{
    <span>@ViewData.Model.ToShortDateString()</span>
}
```

Comment: These are both good answers, but you actually told me what was happening and made me facepalm. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

every where inside code block to force switching to text mode use `<text></text>` snippet.

```
@{
    DateTime? date = ViewData.Model;
    string displayDate = "";

    if(date.HasValue) {
         <text>
               @date.Value.ToShortDateString()
         </text>
    }
}
```

cheers!